# Are i < N+1 and i <= N different?

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, comparison

I used to know that There is no difference between `i <= N` and `i < N+1` 
However, when I enter `6 6` to program. 

if `i <= N` then it print

> 1 6 6 
>  6 1 1 
>  2 3 3 
>  3 2 2

otherwise

> 1 6 6 
>  6 1 1 
>  2 3 3 
>  3 2 2 
>  3 2 2 
>  2 3 3

I can't figure out why it make a difference

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

typedef long long LNT;

LNT gcd(LNT a, LNT b)
{
    if( b == 0)
        return a;

    return gcd(b, a%b);
}

int main()
{
    LNT red, green;
    LNT GCD;
    cin >> red >> green;

    GCD = gcd(red, green);

    //for(LNT i = 1; i<sqrtl(GCD)+1; i++)
    for(LNT i = 1; i<=sqrtl(GCD); i++)   // <- This Line cause the difference 
    {
        if( GCD % i == 0)
        {
            cout << i << " " << red/i << " " << green/i <<endl;
            if( i != GCD/i )
            {
                LNT k = GCD/i;
                cout << k << " " << red/k << " " << green/k <<endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `N == MAX_INT_VALUE` then `N+1` overflows and they are different

Comment: @csharpfolk: That would be `INT_MAX` in C, and `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` in C++. Overflow makes `INT_MAX+1` undefined, so you can't reason about it anymore, but `N <= INT_MAX` is rather pointless anyway (assuming `N` is an int, of course).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is true only for integer values. As `sqrtl` returns `long double`, in case it's fractional then for the fraction it will still differ if you compare original with fraction and `+1` where one another integer fits:

```
! 2 <= 1.5
2 < 1.5+1
```

Comment: I had a  misconception of for-loop.. I thought it would implicitly cast to non-floating type.. Thanks!

Comment: @Eureuerung: The for-loop casts the _result_ of the comparison to `int` or `bool`. (This is why you shouldn't ask C/C++ questions: C and C++ have subtle differences like this. )

Comment: @MSalters: I think Eureuerung was talking about right side of comparison rather than full condition.

Comment: @ZbynekVyskovsky-kvr000: A for-loop can contain pretty much any expression as its conditional expression. Which part(s) of the subexpression would be cast? I.e. `for (char* p = ...; p && *p; ...)` is not an unusual conditional expression.

Answer (score 2):

`sqrtl` return `long double` in this case your assumption:

> no difference between `i <= N` and `i < N+1`

is wrong.

Comment: Oh.. I found out that it works fine when I cast sqrtl(GCD) to (long long) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well,there is no difference between `i<=n` and `i < n+1` as both of them runs till only `n` but what u doing is `sqrt` which returns long double and for them not necessarily to be same.

Comment: There is a difference in some cases. See accepted answer.